# Nuget: NU1001 The dependency * could not be resolved. (Error: ...has timed out after 100000ms.)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, package, nuget

I have cloned a repo from a friend and while I am doing Restore NugetPackages a lot of packages fails to get.

In output I get a lot of records like:

`log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json'.
log  : The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/libuv/index.json'.
log  : The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/libuv/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/moq/index.json'.
log  : The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/moq/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/index.json'.
log  : The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.`

`/*...CODE REMOVED FOR READABILITY...*/`

`log  : The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json'.
error: The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
error: Failed to retrieve information from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json'.
error:   The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.`

**Tools:**
**Visual Studio 2015 Community, update 3.**

**dotnet --version** 1.0.0-preview2-003131

**Nuget 3.5.0**

My Solution Explorer look like in the image bellow: 
[image]

One **package.json** file
`
{
    "title": "Ghp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Ghp",
    "copyright": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],

```
"packOptions": {
    "tags": [ "ghp" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    }
},

"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
},

"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
        "imports": [
            "dnxcore50",
            "portable-net451+win8"
        ]
    },
    "net46": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    }
},

"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
  "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
  "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace": "4.3.0"
}
```

}`

If anyone knows, give me a hint How to resolve the problem with Nuget restore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because I had multiple versions of `Microsoft .NET Core 1.x.x - SDK 1.x.x Preview-x` installed and the same for `Microsoft .NET Core 1.x.x - VS 2015 Tooling Preview-x`.

The solution was to Uninstall all those old **SDK** and **VS 2015 Tooling** and download and install latest versions available on https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

After that, Packages was restored correctly and solution was Rebuilt successfully.

---

Now I have this set of tools:
- `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003131 (x64)`,
- `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2`,
- `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.3 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003156 (x64)`,
- `Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.0 - Runtime (x64)`,
- `Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3`

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, thanks for care. I have to wait a predefined interval of time until can accept the answer which resolved the issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you access the sources in browser you are restoring from, for example, https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/index.json? If yes, you can use the following method as a temporary solution:

1. Download those packages from the [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/) manually.
2. Set a local repository and add those download packages into.
3. Restore the package from the local repository. Before that, you need add the local repository to the package Sources:Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources.

**Note that**: The package "FindPackagesByIdAsync" should be a customer package, it could not be downloaded before it been pushed to the NuGet.org or server. Need to get this package and set it into the local repository.

If that sources could not be accessed, you need to check your network settings.

Comment: Normally, this timeout should be either configurable or directly proportional to the file size. This problem is really annoying. Microsoft should have fixed it yesterday already. I still get this in VS2022.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in vs 2019 too.

I had installed .net core sdk 3.1 and 5 on my windows 10.

After uninstall .net core 3.1 , this problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My "fix" was to build my solution a few dozen times.

Every time it downloaded something extra. And in the end it was done.

Microsoft must decide to fix this. It is 100% counterproductive. The timeout should be larger and configurable and it should probably be proportional to the file size too.

On top of that, it seems that packages are downloaded in parallel, which [although it is good, it also] makes the situation much worse when it comes to download delay and timeouts.

This problem existed for ever and it still exists in VS2022. It is pretty pathetic.